# function inside a function in android

Tags: java, android

what is this technique in java and android? 
please give basics about this technique

```
    objlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) 
        {
            Cursor cr=(Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
            int _id=cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex("_id"));                
            callview(_id);              
        }

    });
```

thank you...

Comment: I think the question was ok - @appu has seen a code snippet and does not understand what the anonymous class technique is or how to find further info on it.  It's no worse than many questions on SO IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [anonymous class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) - very popular for ActionListeners where you create them just where you need them.  In your example, each time you create an instance of the `OnItemClickListener` via the `new` keyword you can specify the `onItemClick` behaviour (via the method) right where it's needed and bind it appropriately.  This is all done in a succinct syntax and scope.

Answer (score 0):

This techinque is known as `anonymous inner classes`

Thanks
Deepak